# Hibernate how to do Self referencing Inheritance Mapping when the self reference points to the base type

Tags: java, hibernate

Given a table "regions", that have a type field indicating a row is either a "place"(type id 1) or a "attraction"(type_id 2), and also have a parent id that refers to the same table as to explain a region belongs to another where a null value indicates its at the top level. A place can belong to an attraction and an attraction can belong to a place. It is a ManyToOne mapping obviously.

id | name | type_id | parent_id
1 | New York | 1 | null
2 | Central park | 2 | 1

I am using the Inheritance Mapping:

@MappedSuperClass
public Class Region {

```
private Integer id;
private String name;
private RegionType type;
private Region parent;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name="name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name
}

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "type_id")
public RegionType getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(RegionType type) {
    this.type = type;
}

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
public Region getParent() {
    return parent;
}

public void setParent(Region parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}
}
```

and the two sub classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="regions")
public class Place extends Region {
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="regions")
public class Attractions extends Region {
}
```

However when I am running, the following exception is thrown:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.mystuff.Place.parent references an unknown entity: com.mystuff.Region
```

And I can understand where it comes from, as Region is not an entity.

However, as I explained before, a type of region can have any type of region as parent. If the type of parent region is fixed, I can definitely declare that as the return type in the getParent method. However based on business rules, it's impossible to know what is the parent type before the data is read.

What are suggested to address my problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Region should be annotated with `@Entity`, not with `@MappedSuperclass`.

The default inheritance type is SINGLE_TABLE, which is exactly what you want. You then use the [`DiscriminatorColumn`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/DiscriminatorColumn.html) annotation on Region to specify which column is used as the discriminator, and [`DiscriminatorValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/DiscriminatorColumn.html) on the subclasses to specify what value to use for the subclass in the discriminator column.

The linked javadocs have examples that should help.

Also, please rename `Attractions` to `Attraction`. An instance of that class is one attraction, not many of them.

Comment: I see. What if Place maps to more than one region_type? Can I specify a range of values in DiscriminatorValue? (like type_id < 100 marks a Place and >= 100 marks an attraction?)
And thanks for the Attraction renaming!

Comment: What's the point of having multiple values to identify a unique thing: the type Attraction (or the type Place)? No, that's not possible.

Comment: Hibernate has a DiscriminatorFormula annotation, though. But I'd rather not use that. But I'd rather not use that. If you have different kinds of places, create subclasses with their own discriminator value, or add an additional column/field placeType in Place.